# How does this loop work?

Tags: macros

This code is supposed to be a for loop that `\inlcude` 45 files called 1.tex through 45.tex into the main file. However I don't quite understand anything except for the `\newcommand` so can someone give a somewhat more detailed explanation. I have never seen LaTeX written this way, can someone point to good resources to learn more?

```
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\includepatternloop[5]{%
  \include{#5#3#1#4}%
  \ifnum#1<\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\number#2}{} %
     \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
  \fi
}%
\includepatternloop{1}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}%
```

Comment: There you go: [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)

Comment: By the way... I think you would need to learn TeX programming to *understand the explanation* anyway so no point asking for explanation.

Comment: And... I usually recommend people to learn Lua to program in TeX instead.

Comment: The code is wrong, because the extension should never be passed when doing `\include`

Comment: @egreg As far as I know the extension .tex must be omitted with the command `\include` until LaTeX 2021/06/01. This will be added automatically during processing. As of LaTeX 2021/06/01, the extension is only added if it has not already been specified by the user.

Comment: By the way: I, Ulrich Diez, am the one to be blamed for errors in the code presented, e.g., the extension  ".tex" with `\include` - the code stems from an [answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639305/118714) to the question "How to use for loop to input files".

Comment: @user202729 which is wrong on so many levels! How should people experience the joy of something working after finding and circumventing all the pitfalls there are to TeX-programming! Lua is too simple :)

Answer (score 4):

As
[@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639315/how-does-this-loop-work/639335?noredirect=1#comment1593646_639315)
and
[@UlrichDiez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639315/how-does-this-loop-work/639335?noredirect=1#comment1593656_639315)
layed out, the usage of `\includepatternloop` has a potential error: Inside of
`\include` the `.tex` ending shouldn't be used (newer versions of LaTeX detect
this, but to be safe just omit it). So better would've been to use
`\includepatternloop{1}{45}{}{}{./chapters/}` in your case.

## Explanation

Ok, lets take a close look at your code.

The first (and simpler macro) to look at is `\exchange`. Everything it does is
taking two arguments and switching there order. It will remove one set of braces
if the argument is braced. So both

```tex
\exchange{a}{b}
\exchange ab
```

will result in `ba` after one step of expansion.

The other macro is your `\includepatternloop`. It'll take 5 arguments, and in
order to keep better track of them I'll name them here:

1. `<current>`
2. `<stop>`
3. `<base>`
4. `<post>`
5. `<dir>`

The two arguments `<base>` and `<dir>` are a bit redundant and only two distinct
arguments for semantic reasons. You could drop one of the two and simply put
there contents together into one argument (but we'll look at a simplified
version later).

So what does your macro do?
First it puts together a file name from the different arguments and includes
them

```tex
  \include{#5#3#1#4}%
```

is in our named argument version the same as
`\include{<dir><base><current><post>}` so on the first iteration of the call
`\includepatternloop{1}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}` this will use
`\include{./chapters/1.tex}` (`<base>` is empty).

Next line:

```tex
  \ifnum#1<\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\number#2}{} %
```

This line checks whether we're done. `\ifnum` is a test comparing two numbers.
`#1` is the `<current>` iteration, and this checks whether it is smaller than
`#2` (in an overly complicated way). There is a pitfall in TeX's number parsing
that is it expands things until it finds something that can't be part of a
number. To stop this expansion one usually puts a space after it (that space
will be gobbled) or (to be on the really safe side) a `\relax` token.

To understand that line we need to know that `\expandafter` basically expands
the token *after* the next token then removes itself and the next token does its
thing (and `\expandafter` does so in one step). So
`\expandafter\exchange\expandafter` will first expand the second `\expandafter`,
that one will expand the `\number` behind the brace, and `\number` reads in
anything TeX could consider a number and leaves the number in arabic digits. So
`\number#2` is a normalisation. TeX's number parsing is stopped by the closing
brace (that can't be a number, right?). So when the `\expandafter`s are done our
input looks like `\exchange{<stop (normalised)>}{}` followed by a space. Now
`\exchange` swaps the two arguments, the second is empty, so this becomes `<stop (normalised)>` followed by a space. That space terminates TeX's number parsing
for the second `\ifnum` number.

All the `\exchange` did was allow that the normalisation with `\number` would be
ended by the closing brace and the space at the end of the line is used to
terminate `\ifnum`'s number parsing instead of `\number`'s.

Now `\ifnum` compares `<current>` with `<stop (normalised)>`. If the condition
(smaller than) is not met, everything up to the `\fi` two rows down is gobbled
and the macro is done. Else the next iteration is called with the line

```tex
    \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
```

The `\exchange` will swap the rest of this line with the `\fi`, so now the `\fi`
ends the `\ifnum` block and afterwards

```tex
\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
```

is evaluated.

We have a few `\expandafter` again. Those will first expand the `\number` before
`\includepatternloop` is run. That `\number` will expand until TeX has a
complete number. To do so it expands `\numexpr`. Now `\numexpr` is a number
parsing macro as well, this one allows to do basic calculations, and will be
terminated by either something that can't be part of a number (but semi-ignoring
spaces, no need to further dig here) and is no valid operator (it supports `+`,
`-`, `*`, `/` and parenthesis). It will be terminated by `\relax` (which it will
gobble!). So after `\number\numexpr<current>+1\relax` is expanded once the new
contents of the first braced group will be `<next>` which is the result of
`<current>+1`.

The `\expandafter`s are done and our new input line looks like this:

`\includepatternloop{<next>}{<stop>}{<base>}{<post>}{<dir>}`

resulting in the next iteration.

---

## Alternative implementation

That macro could be a bit simplified. Two of the arguments can be combined into
one `<pre>` argument. And the number parsing in the `\ifnum` row is a bit over
the top. Instead I'd use a two step approach, one front end macro doing the
normalisations, and one macro actually doing the loop. `\the` is similar to
`\number`, but doesn't work on literal numeric input (so `\number5` is fine and
would result in 5, `\the5` throws an error), but is a tad faster (and for
`\numexpr` it doesn't make a difference). Input normalisations are done with
`\numexpr` instead of `\number` (this allows to calculate `<start>` and `<stop>`
on the spot, so `\includepatternloop{1+6}{100-50}{./chapters/}{.tex}` would be
fine). The `;`s will stop the `\numexpr` and serve as argument delimiters
because the inner loop is defined with plain syntax `\def`.

```tex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\includepatternloop[2]% <start> and <stop> are grabbed, rest curried
  {%
    \expandafter\@includepatternloop\the\numexpr#1\expandafter;\the\numexpr#2;
  }
\protected\def\@includepatternloop#1;#2;#3#4% <- will grab 2 arguments right delimited by `;` and 2 normal ones
  {%
    \include{#3#1#4}%
    \ifnum#1<#2 % <- space after #2 terminates number parsing
      \exchange{\expandafter\@includepatternloop\the\numexpr#1+1;#2;{#3}{#4}}%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
```

The new frontend syntax is `\includepatternloop{<start>}{<stop>}{<pre>}{<post>}`
and to include every file in `./chapters/` that is named `A<number>B` from 1
to 45 you'd use

```tex
\includepatternloop{1}{45}{./chapters/A}{B}
```

Remember to not include the file extension `.tex` for `\include`.

Comment: The space used for terminating number parsing with `#2` might be spurious in the first iteration in case the number in that iteration comes from a `\chardef`-token or the like TeX-<number>-quantity whereafter TeX does not scan for one optional space. That's why in my variant I did the `\number`-thingie for normalization.

Comment: @UlrichDiez still the `\exchange` thing is a bit over the top. In that case, this isn't expandable anyways, use `\relax` :)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the code is to do, for `N` going from 1 to 45,

```
\include{./chapters/N.tex}
```

which is *wrong* to begin with, because the extension `.tex` should ***never*** be passed with `\include`. I'll gloss over this aspect.

I don't find it particularly instructive, but here you go. The idea is to do

```
\include{#5#3#1#4}
```

and then do a test on whether `#1` is still less than `#2`. If it is, then

```
\includepatternloop{#1+1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5]
```

is called, where `#1+1` denotes the previous value increased by 1.

One might be tempted to do a simplified version, namely

```
\newcommand\includepatternloop[5]{%
  \include{#5#3#1#4}%
  \ifnum#1<#2
    \expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
  \fi
}
```

but this would be bad, because it would not eat the trailing `\fi` and this is why the strategy with `\exchange` is employed.

Let's start from the conditional: it can be simplified to

```
\ifnum#1<#2
```

when the second argument to `\includepatternloop` is an explicit number.
The `\exchange` is used to have `#2` expanded (it might be a macro) but to still have a trailing space that avoids the need of `\relax` (interesting trick).

If the test returns false, nothing more is done, so let's look at the interesting part when the test returns true, say at the first step: we have

```
\includepatternloop{1}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}
```

that becomes

```
\include{./chapters/1.tex}
\ifnum 1<\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\number#2}{} %
  \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}}%
\fi
```

The token following `<` is expanded to look for a number and this eventually results in

```
\ifnum 1<45 %
  \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}}%
\fi
```

OK, the test is true, so we get

```
  \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}}%
\fi
```

Note that `\fi` is not yet removed. Now `\exchange` is performed, which results in

```
  \exchange{\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}}%
\fi
```

and this is where the `\fi` is removed, because we're left with

```
\fi
\expandafter\includepatternloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}}
```

The expansion of `\fi` is empty and the work can continue: `\expandafter` does its job eventually hitting `\number` so we're left with

```
\includepatternloop{2}{45}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}
```

and the job is restarted.

How can it be done with less tricks? Of course you can use `expl3` that needs no `\expandafter` and no tricks.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\includepatternloop}{mmmmm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \include { #5 #3 ##1 #4 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If I try the above with `\includepatternloop{1}{5}{}{.tex}{./chapters/}` and

```
\typeout{\string\include{#5 #3 ##1 #4}}
```

in the loop body just to see what would happen, the console would show

```
\include{./chapters/1.tex}
\include{./chapters/2.tex}
\include{./chapters/3.tex}
\include{./chapters/4.tex}
\include{./chapters/5.tex}
```

The main point here is that `##1` in the code refers to the current integer in the loop created by `\int_step_inline:nnn`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `.tex` thingy being wrong... :)

Comment: By the way: I, Ulrich Diez, am the one to be blamed for errors in the code presented in the question, e.g., the extension  ".tex" with `\include` - the code stems from an [answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639305/118714) to the question "How to use for loop to input files". There in an edit I switched from `\input` (primitive) to `\include` and overlooked the need of removing the filename-extension.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Nice code nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Maybe, yes. But I could not write nice code if you did not teach me so many things over the years. :-)